# I am getting error as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks

[image]

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

Comment: what's your vue version?

Comment: Vue isn't defined because of the errors at the top. Looks like you have some kind of HTML in those files?

Answer (score 0):

you probably have vue 3 installed but you are using a guide for vue 2, make sure the version of the guide / tutorial / plugin is the same that you are actually going to use